# How to make a thread wait for other threads to do a specific task in python

Tags: python, multithreading

i have multiple threads doing the same job : to calculate a distance and put it in a list than each thread needs to compare it to the other threads and do a certain task.
how do i make a thread wait for the others to finish the task ( and having others task to follow up joins won't work in this case)

Comment: Why not kill the thread when it's done? Then you could wait for all workers to complete and open new threads to process the results. I don't know if that's good for you since you gave us no explanation on what is the task or what's your code for doing it

Comment: i need the same thread to continue other task for a simulation.

Comment: Re, "I need the same thread to..." In a program that uses multiple threads for computation, it's often a smart idea to design the program so that it does not matter which thread does the work when there's work to be done, but...

Comment: ...If you're using the standard Python implementation, then there is no performance benefit from using multiple threads for computation because of the [Global Interpreter Lock (a.k.a., "the GIL")](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: as i said @jameslarge it's for a simulation i need each thread to represent a sensor that calculate distance.

Answer (score 3):

There's a name for what you want, it's called a `Barrier`.  I don't know enough about the Python ecosystem to know whether there's a ready-made one that you can just use, but here's what it is:

It's an object that contains a count (initially greater than zero), and a condition variable.  It has a method, `await()`.

The `await()` method decrements the count, and then;

- It signals the condition variable and returns if the count became zero, or
- It waits on the condition variable until the count equals zero, and *then* it returns.

If you initialize a Barrier with count = N, and then N threads `await()` it, none of the threads will "get past the barrier" (i.e., return from `await()`) until all of the threads have "arrived at the barrier" (i.e., called `await()`).

`Barrier` often is implemented as `CyclicBarrier`, which is the same thing with the additional feature that it automatically resets the count to its original value when the barrier opens.

---

Update:  There is a `threading.Barrier` class in the standard library for Python3 (v. 3.2 and later).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects

Comment: Thanks , i think this is exactly what i'm looking for  it's better than what i'm using ( waiting for the Queue to be full )